# Meaning of “Revision” in ipset output

Tags: iptables, ipset

With iptables version 1.4.21 and RHEL7.2 and ipset v6.19, I have been observing a difference in ipsets. It seems that the ipsets are displayed as follows:-

```
root@system> ipset list 
Name: BlockList 
Type: hash:ip 
Revision: 1 
Header: family inet hashsize 4096 maxelem 2147483648 
Size in memory: 65680 
References: 0 
Members:
```

---

```
Name: BlockList2 
Type: hash:ip 
Revision: 3 
Header: family inet hashsize 4096 maxelem 2147483648 
Size in memory: 65680
References: 0 
Members:
```

What is the significance of this revision? Could anyone let me know.

On RHEL6.6 and an older version of iptables 1.4.7 and ipset v6.11, I could get this as the output:-

```
Name: myset 
Type: hash:net 
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 
Size in memory: 16848 
References: 0 
Members: 27.8.0.0/13 
58.16.0.0/15 
14.144.0.0/12
```

Here I can see that there is no such thing called Revision.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.